# Cannot set breakpoint at if else statement in Chrome developer tool

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

In the old version of chrome, I can set breakpoint at if else statement to view the value of object in if condition.

But when upgraded chrome to the latest version, I cannot do it now. The breakpoint is auto place inside the if block. 
It make difficult to debugging, has to place two breakpoint if I want to debug at if else statement

My source code is not minify or truncate anything else.

Comment: Are you able to provide a code example where this doesn't work? I'm able to set a breakpoint on the line that has the `if` statement and view the value fine. Sometimes source maps can cause the debugger to set a breakpoint at a different line. See my working example https://i.imgur.com/zamosZp.png

Comment: I cannot also, though I am debugging TypeScript instead of vanilla JavaScript, though this also did work in previous versions. Extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

As for Chrome 67, a workaround is that you need to click on the same line in the name.js file to set a breakpoint. A breakpoint will be added automatically in the corresponding name.ts file. It's kind of awkward, but at least makes you stop at the if statement.